# Getting id from dynamically created from multiple checkbox group?

Tags: android, checkboxlist, android-checkbox

I have created multiple set of checkbox(depending on server response ).Now i want to know which checkboxs are clicked,

What i have done is to create checkbox is

```
  for(  k = 0; k < stringList.size(); k++) {  
                       cb[k] = new CheckBox(this);
                       cb[k].setText(stringList.get(k)); 
                       cb[k].setTag(feedbackdetails.get(i).getLabel());     
                       cb[k].setId(k);
                       cb[k].setTextSize(ws.get_width());


                       ll.addView(cb[k]);
                       allcheckbox.add(cb[k]); }
```

i try to get the id on another button click

```
for(int i=0; i < allcheckbox.size(); i++){
                stringcheckbox[i] = allcheckbox.get(i).getText().toString();


                try {
                    if(cb[i].isChecked()){
                         checkid = cb[i].getId();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

i am able to get id of last checkboxgroup.not getting any other check box id.

Comment: i have resolved this problem and and answer present at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017308/getting-checkboxid-for-dynamically-created-checkbox/35313544#35313544

Answer (score 0):

is the checkid, in checkid = cb[i].getId(); mean string???

if you declare the checkid is string, ofcourse you`ll only get the last id of checked checkbox. change the checkid to array string or array list. it can hold many value, so every checked checkbox id can be stored.

Comment: it is not a single set of check box, means i have a label "Check Box 1" under that 3 check box then a label "Check Box 2" under that 4 check box like that i am able to get the values under the label "Check Box 2" I need to get ids of checkbox1 also